# Update all duplicate sub-nodes in xml file.

Tags: php, xml

I am try to edit xml file. The following code is working perfectly if the subnode is unique. But in my xml file there is some duplicate subnode. so when I try to edit them I face this error:

> Cannot assign to an array of nodes (duplicate subnodes or attr detected)

I am trying to achieve that when I edit the xml file, all subnode with same name is also updated.

`CODE:`

```
$config = new SimpleXmlElement('xml.xml',null,true);
// UPDATE
$config->Connection_Type = ' abcdef';
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $config->asXml();
```

`example:`
In my xml file the following nodes are same(different by group). What i trying to do is when i edit the value of `Connection_Type` to `abcdef`, it takes effect in both lines.

```
<Connection_Type group="Info/System_Information">DHCP</Connection_Type>
<Connection_Type group="System/Internet_Connection_Type_">DHCP</Connection_Type>
```

`expected output:`

```
<Connection_Type group="Info/System_Information">abcdef</Connection_Type>
<Connection_Type group="System/Internet_Connection_Type_">abcdef</Connection_Type>
```

`current output:`

> Cannot assign to an array of nodes (duplicate subnodes or attr detected)

so how to achieve upper things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
foreach($config->Connection_Type as $node)
       $node[0] = 'abcdef';
```